# Error with cmake when trying to load yamlcpp

Tags: cmake

I've tried to install Astron-master using cmake, however there seems to be a problem with cmake not recognizing yamlcpp when doing so. I was told that this is a cmake error and not yamlcpp, since I was able build yamlcpp successfully. cmake gives this error

```
Could NOT find YamlCpp (missing:  YAMLCPP_LIBRARY YAMLCPP_LIBRARY_DIR) 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:116 (message):
  You need yamlcpp to build this, build yamlcpp in the 'dependencies/'
  directory, or install it as a system package
```

I'm using `yaml-cpp-0.5.1` on windows 7

I have images showing my folders and it helps get a better idea, but I am not allowed to upload until I have 10 rep.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/Astron/Astron/tree/master/dependencies)?  If so, did you build Yaml to have static or dynamic libs?